# С клавиатуры вводится трехзначное натуральное число. Найти, сколько раз в нем встречается цифра 3

Tags: c

Надо просто найти количество троек в трехзначном числе, не в массиве

Comment: С 16 января русский запрещен только на Украине, но не на ruSO. Переведите на русский, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int n = 543;
int m = 0;
for(;n;n/=10) if (n%10 == 3) m++;
printf("%d\n",m);
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 1):

любое число можно разбить на цифры

1. превратив его в строку и пройдя по символам
2. последовательно деля число на 10 пока не будет достигнут 0 и смотря остаток от деления

воспользуйтесь этим